# Is it possible to get the most popular tweets in a topic using the Twitter API?

Tags: api, twitter

I curious if it's possible to retrieve the most popular tweets for a given topic using the API (according to retweets or favourites)? I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to find out what the most popular tweets are if not for a certain time period then at the current moment, the closest I've come to solving this problem is getting the trending topics using the `GET trends/place method`, but I'm not sure what I can do from there. Any advice appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The search API has a `result_type` parameter that you can set to popular, like this:

```
  https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=topic&result_type=popular
```