# Is it possible to get the most popular tweets in a topic using the twitter API on NIFI?

Tags: twitter, apache-nifi, data-analysis

I am using the GetTwitter processor on NIFI to collect tweets for a data analysis project. However, I am mostly interested on collecting tweets that could have a noticeable impact on public opinion.

I know there is a way to filter your results using EvaluateJsonPath and RouteOnAttribute. However, this method is very inefficient for what I need. It takes thousands of results to get a tweet with more than 0 likes. There should be a way for the api to quickly collect only top results on the topic I am researching.

The following post says that there is a `result_type` parameter that would let me do this: [Is it possible to get the most popular tweets in a topic using the Twitter API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33685560/is-it-possible-to-get-the-most-popular-tweets-in-a-topic-using-the-twitter-api).
However, I have no idea how to apply this to nifi.

I would appreaciate any help, thank you :)

Comment: Probably not using GetTwitter, but you can use InvokeHTTP for more complex REST API interactions https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.13.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.InvokeHTTP/

Comment: @Sdairs Thank you for the comment, I have been trying to do that but I can't seem to find any information on how to add the authentification parameters to this http call on the processor->   https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=topic&result_type=popular

Comment: In the InvokeHTTP config, click the + icon to add a Dynamic property. This lets you add headers to the HTTP request, so you can pass in tokens as needed.